# Passing Multiple Arguments to Generator in tf.data.Datasets.from_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, tensorflow-datasets

I have a folder containing images of various sizes. I need to resize them all to (160,120) and create a tf.data.Dataset. For this I used the tf.data.Dataset.from_generator. But I can't seem to figure out how to send the other arguments to the generator like target_size, class_mode etc other than the directory itself.
[NOTE: I am using Tensorflow 2.0 Beta1]

The ***args*** parameter takes tf.Tensor objects and uses them as arguments for the generator. I tried passing all the arguments as a list.

```
# gen is the ImageDataGenerator

real_imgs_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen.flow_from_directory,
                                      args = 
                                            (data_path,    # DIRECTORY
                                            (160, 128),    # TARGET SIZE
                                            'rgb',         # COLOR MODE
                                             None,         # CLASSES
                                             None,         # CLASS MODE
                                             32,           # BATCH SIZE
                                             True),        # SHUFFLE
                                        output_types = tf.float32, 
                                        output_shapes = ([None,160,128,3])
                                       )
```

What I wanted to do was to pass the images through the generator, and the generator would spit out images batch by batch and create a tf.data.Dataset. However, when I try to run the above snippet, I get an error saying:-

**"ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type () to a Tensor"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue that I reported there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33133

The proposed solution adapted to your case is:

```py
gen_mod = gen.flow_from_directory(directory=data_path, target_size=(
    160, 128), class_mode=None, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

real_imgs_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen_mod,
    output_types=tf.float32,
    output_shapes=([None, 160, 128, 3])
)
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The solution using lambda worked in part.
But in my current environment(TensorFlow2.6.0), I have observed that the values generated by lambda won't reset between epochs.

As a workaround, it is possible to make generators have double layers as shown below.

```
def new_gen():
    gen_mod = gen.flow_from_directory(directory=data_path, target_size=(
        160, 128), class_mode=None, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

    for x in gen_mod:
        yield x

real_imgs_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    new_gen,
    output_types=tf.float32,
    output_shapes=([None, 160, 128, 3])
)
```